# Xcode Contents.json missing from working copy

Tags: xcode8

I recently upgraded to XCode8 build settings and finally got rid of an annoying issue asking me to do this, only to have it replaced by another issue I cannot seem to resolve.

The issue is that the Contents.json file in my launch assets folder is missing from my working copy. Please can someone tell me the easiest way to resolve this issue.

I have searched for similar questions and as a result I have already tried

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Source Code Commit

if anoyone can enlighten me on exactly what a working copy is, then I would also be grateful for that.

Comment: you can delete the launch assets folder and create new one.

Comment: seems a bit of a PITA, is there not some option somewhere to ask Xcode to rebuild the Contents.json?  Also the file exists and the app works.

Comment: ok try to delete xuserdata

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to do that (what is in and where is it)

Comment: Right click on the project in the Xcode and click on Show in Finder than in the finder click on project file and click show Package Content, than you will see there will be a xcuserdata folder, just delete that, clean project, rebuild and than see.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions, however I now have 2 more files missing from my working copy (both of which were in xcuserdata!)

Comment: I have just removed the launch assets folder and created a brand new one. The original error is still there. I noticed during the removal and addition process various build issues appearing and dissappearing below my original issue and these issues (unassigned children etc) were listed under the app, rather than under the app project.

Comment: are you using source control for the project?

Comment: Yes, However I need to explain a bit more. I have commited the project twice under xcode source control but my primary source control method is to copy any changes to the project files to a separate folder which is linked to a remote git repository.

Comment: I just tried to commit inside Xcode and I got an error message that the file mentioned in my original issue cannot be committed because it is not linked to any file know to Git! I then tried again and finally the issue has gone!. Hurray!! Thanks Shabir, how do I accept your answer?

Comment: Just upvote my answer in the comments.

Comment: check my answer regarding working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working copy is the copy you have checked out to your working area. It doesn't matter if it is a branch or from the trunk. It's what you are working on.

You can switch between branches (or more correctly copies) of the same parent with svn switch. This will basically say, what's different between the current working copy and the branch I am switch to. It then performs an update on your current working copy to the revision of branch you switch to.

So working copy is your checkout, however it was obtained.